# Jquery UI Tabs Widget - Href and aria-controls

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, href, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm having a big headache here...

I'm working on updating an old website using jQuery 1.3 to jQuery 1.10.
And now, I'm struggling since 2 days now about how to change a tab's URL dynamically in order to reload it with a new content into the same tab.

I clarify a bit. Let's say I have a single tab.
When I click on this tab, I want "page1.php" to be shown there. Here no prob ! My page1.php content is well displayed. inside it, I have a link "go to next page" which should display the next page (page2.php) inside my tab.
When I click on this link, I'd like to tell my tab to change its href attribute and reload itself with the new content.

I saw on the official doc that "url" and "title" are deprecated, and that we should use "aria-controls" instead.

I tried a lot to deal with it, but still can't find any solution around it.

here's what the old website used to do:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("url", "1", "page2.php");
$("#tabs").tabs('load', 1);
```

here's the first piece of code I tried:

```
$("#tabs").attr('aria-controls', "page2.php");
$("#tabs").tabs('load', 1);
```

I even tried to refresh but still didn't work:

```
$("#tabs").attr('aria-controls', "page2.php");
$("#tabs").tabs('refresh');
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the 3rd was better for my brain. Here's a solution to do it:

```
function loadURLinTab(tabsWidget, url)
{
    var active = tabsWidget.tabs( "option", "active" );

    tabsWidget.find("ul>li a").eq(active).attr('href', url);
    tabsWidget.tabs('load', active);
}
```

Pass the jQuery object (of the Tabs Widget) and the URL you want to load in the tab, and here you go !

Answer (score 0):

This is another method of how the url can be changed on a click, using the jquery-ui api methods.

First set up the tabs

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
        ui.newTab.context.href = $("#linkID").attr('href');
    }
});
```

Then on the link click activate the tab, which will update the tab href to the link href.

```
$("#linkID").on('click', function() {
    $("tabs").tabs('option','active',1);
});
```

Hope this helps someone.